# WiX Toolset Use User-defined variables

Tags: wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022, wix4

I'd like to use *User-defined variables* in my WiX Toolset Project.
If I try to use them, the building process will fail and I get the Error Message *WIX0150 Undefined preprocessor variable '$(MyVariable)'.*

I followed the documention from WiX Toolset itself: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/preprocessor/

My project looks like this:

wixproj-file

```html
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.3">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <DefineConstants>
            <?define MyVariable = "Filepath" ?>
        </DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Component-file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="HandlerCmp" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <File Source="$(MyVariable)" />
        </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumpled in the projects properties over the solution.
Under *Project -> Properties -> Build* you can define Preprocessor variables.
This will create an *DefineConstants* entry in the wixproj file like the follow one:

```html
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.3">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <DefineConstants>MyVariable=Filepath;MyVariable2=Filepath2</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The usage stase the same like descriped in the question:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Fragment>
        <Component Id="HandlerCmp" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <File Source="$(MyVariable)" />
        </Component>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```